# Is 'swaddles' a word?

Tags: verbs, nouns, is-it-a-word

I swear I've heard the term *swaddles* used before, but when I look it up, I only get definitions for *swaddle*. I believe it was used as a noun, but the definition of *swaddle* is throwing me off.

Here's how it would be used if I'm correct:

> Her brother was born while she was still *in swaddles*.

So, it would be used as a term for the garments that a baby or toddler is being swaddled in.

The definition of [swaddle](https://www.lexico.com/definition/swaddle) from the Oxford Lexico is:

> Wrap (someone, especially a baby) in garments or cloth.

Is *swaddles* really a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

Swaddle is also a [noun](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/swaddle), as seen in the third definition on Collins Dictionary:

> 3. a cloth, bandage, etc. used for swaddling

And also the fourth definition from the same page under *British English*:

> 4. *mainly US*
>    swaddling clothes

In a search on Google Books for “in swaddles”, you can see many examples of its usage. Such as this one from *In the Heart of the Garden* by Leah Fleming:

> ‘Don’t you touch them, they’re mine! Help me wrap them tight *in swaddles*’

And this one from *Odd enough, to be sure! or, Emilius in the world, Volume 1* by A. H. J. La Fontaine:

> ‘In short, the child was not tied up *in swaddles*, as the mother wished him’